# org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token on connecting to soap webservice

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2

I am using `ksoap2` library for webservice call :

I get error at line:

```
 androidHttpTransport.call(action, envelope);
```

Full Code :

```
public String executeSoapWebservice(String urlString, String action, String method, String nameSpace, JSONObject postParams){

    String response ="";

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(nameSpace, method);

    try{
        JSONObject ob = postParams;
        Iterator iterator = ob.keys();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            String key = (String)iterator.next();
            String value = ob.getString(key);

            request.addProperty(key, value);
        }
    }catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    envelope.dotNet = true;

    try {
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(urlString);
        //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
        androidHttpTransport.call(action, envelope);
        // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.

        //Object result = (Object) envelope.getResponse();
        SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
        if(result != null) {
            //Get the first property and change the label text
            response = result.getProperty(0).toString();
            //response = result.toString();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        response = "";
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Check your nameSpace, method and urlString.

Comment: I get this exception only in case when response contains multidimentional jsonarray. otherwise it works fine.

Comment: it works fine for the following response:{"status":"200","statusMsg":"OK","EncHid":"42712839","data":[{"acdYear":"2015 - 2014"},{"acdYear":"2000 - 2003"},{"acdYear":"2004 - 2008"},{"acdYear":"2014 - 2016"}]}                                                           But does not works for: {"status":"200","statusMsg":"OK","EncHid":"30066430","data":[{"qualLevl":"Intermediate (10+2)","acdYear":"2015 - 2014"},{"qualLevl":"Diploma","acdYear":"2000 - 2003"},{"qualLevl":"Graduate","acdYear":"2004 - 2008"}]}

Comment: Does android have another library for calling soap web service ?

Comment: See here, https://android-arsenal.com/tag/91

Comment: on searching for solution i have added the line androidHttpTransport.debug = true; in the code. But instead i got exception : - java.io.EOFException: source exhausted prematurely

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the web service (I assume it is asp.net) the only way I was able to get passed this problem was by doing two modifications.

On the asp.net side:

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetJSonData()
{
   //service code

    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(passwordData);

    String jsonString = serializedResult.ToString();

    // remove this line
    //Context.Response.Write(serializedResult);

    // return the serialized data as string
    return jsonString;
}
```

then on the Android side change SoapObject to SoapPrimitive

```
// This causes the problem
//SoapObject resultData = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

// Combined with the modification on the asp.net this works
SoapPrimitive resultData = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
```